# about running WEB Rtc sample

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I cloned the files from [google Lab](https://github.com/webrtc/samples) where it says try the live demos.
then I installed npm and i tryied to find the index.js which triggers the program to start, but there were few files which are gulpfile.babel.js / nightwatch.conf.js.

Before try this demo version, I followed the steps where [googleTryCodeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0) presents and in index.js, there was starting with 'use strict'. So I found that code in gulpfile.babel.js and I tried

> node gulpfile.babel.js

and it produces the error, which is

> import gulp from 'gulp'; ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:355:18)
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:15)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1056:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
>
> E:\webRtcProject\test\example\samples>node index.js
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927   throw err;

Is there other way to start this demo version??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samples repository is a collection of standalone HTML/JS pages. You can test them from a simple HTTP server like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

The WebRTC codelab at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web#2 is a different thing.

Comment: that's why I cannot run by other js... thanks for help!